# How to get IP address from sockaddr

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address

I want to try and get the ip address of a client after calling accept.  This is what I have so far, but I just end up getting some long number that is clearly not an ip address.  What could be wrong?

```
int tcp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

sockaddr_in client;
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
socklen_t c_len = sizeof(client);

int acc_tcp_sock = accept(tcp_sock, (sockaddr*)&client, &c_len);
cout << "Connected to: " << client.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That long number *is* the IP address, in integer form (an IP address is just an integer, after all; it's just easier for people to use when we split the octets apart and put it into dot notation).

[You can use `inet_ntoa`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html) to convert the integer value to standard dot notation.

Comment: Note that now `inet_ntoa` is considered deprecated. You should instead use `inet_ntop` which supports more formats.

Answer (score 34):

Seen from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/client.c:

```
// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

// [...]

struct addrinfo *p;
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
```

It uses `inet_ntop`, which is preferred over `inet_ntoa` (non thread-safe) as it handles IPv4 and IPv6 (`AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`) and should be thread-safe I think.

Answer (score 6):

what your are getting is the raw 32 bit integer representation of the IP address.
to get the familiar dot separated string, use   the function:

```
 char * inet_ntoa(struct in_addr addr);
```

that will convert the integer to a static string.

Answer (score 4):

The following is taken from the example https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/epoll-example.c

```
              struct sockaddr in_addr;
              socklen_t in_len;
              int infd;
              char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

              in_len = sizeof in_addr;
              infd = accept (sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
              if (infd == -1)
                {
                  if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||
                      (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
                    {
                      /* We have processed all incoming
                         connections. */
                      break;
                    }
                  else
                    {
                      perror ("accept");
                      break;
                    }
                }

                 s = getnameinfo (&in_addr, in_len,
                 hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
                 sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
                 NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                 if (s == 0){
                     printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
                         "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
                 }
```

Answer (score 3):

While these are good answers, they broke my compile with `-pedantic -std=c99 -Werror`.

From *man 7 socket*

> To allow any type of socket address to be passed to interfaces in the sockets API, the type `struct sockaddr` is defined. The purpose of
>   this type is purely to allow casting of domain-specific socket address
>   types to a "generic" type, so as to avoid compiler warnings about type
>   mismatches in calls to the sockets API.

To get all the relevant data in this page, from glibc-2.17 (RHEL7) I see

```
/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];       /* Address data.  */
  };
```

where SOCKADDR_COMMON is a `uint16_t`. So total size is 16B.

IP (internet protocol) Domain specific, from *man 7 ip*:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};

/* Internet address. */
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
};
```

First try

```
inet_ntoa( ((struct sockaddr_in) peer_addr).sin_addr )
```

Problem

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Second try

```
 inet_ntoa( ((struct sockaddr_in *) &peer_addr)->sin_addr ) ));
```

Problem

```
error: dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
```

Thrid try: inet_pton, more modern anyways, thread safe, takes void*

```
char peer_addr_str[ INET_ADDRSTRLEN ];
inet_ntop( AF_INET, &peer_addr, peer_addr_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

ok, works. Human readable decimal-and-dots string is in `peer_addr_str`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getnameinfo function that is available for Linux and Windows. From Linux man pages https://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo:

> getnameinfo - address-to-name translation in protocol-independent manner

Example for C/C++ (Linux):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char host[NI_MAXHOST]; // to store resulting string for ip
if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, c_len,
                  host, NI_MAXHOST, // to try to get domain name don't put NI_NUMERICHOST flag
                  NULL, 0,          // use char serv[NI_MAXSERV] if you need port number
                  NI_NUMERICHOST    // | NI_NUMERICSERV
               ) != 0) {
   //handle errors
} else {
    printf("Connected to: %s\n", host);     
}
```

This is clean up of @enthusiasticgeek answer. His answer has a working example with accept call.