# Getting destination/if IP addres from accept()?

Tags: c, tcp

Say, I bind `0.0.0.0` port X, listen on it, and then accept new connection.

How can my server find destination IP address the client used to connect to?

Also, via which interface (assuming multihomed server) the SYN arrived?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824279/how-to-get-ip-address-from-sockaddr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getsockname()` call on the socket returned by `accept()` will give you the address of the local end of the connection.

The best way to determine the interface is probably just to match up the local IP address from `getsockname()` against the interface addresses.