# How to get client's IP address

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a client server program that server receive message from client. 
I want to see the client's IP address on the server side. How can I do this?
I would be grateful if you could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give more info on what library you are using to do the client connection ? i.e. Are you using <sys/socket.h> ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824279/how-to-get-ip-address-from-sockaddr

Comment: @rjdkolb I'm using from QTcpsocket.

Comment: I think peerAddress is what you are looking for : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#peerAddress

Comment: @rjdkolb post as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are using `QTcpSocket`, I think `.peerAddress` is what you are looking for.

```
class Server : public QTcpServer {...}
```

On accept

```
void Server::acceptConnection() {
  std::cout << "new connection!\n";
  client = nextPendingConnection();
  std::cout << client->peerAddress().toString();
}
```